# Making a menu button larger when active in Drupal 7

Tags: css, drupal-7

Similar to http://www.austintexas.gov/government I want to make a menu button bigger when it is active.

**Here is my css for my main menu**

```
#mobileMenu_mm1 {
  margin: 10px 20px;
  padding: 3px 0px;}

#navigation {
  margin: 0px auto;
  float: left;}

#main-menu{
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;}

#main-menu ul {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 0px 15px;}

#main-menu li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #333 !important;
  background: rgb(0, 25, 60);
  background: rgba(0, 25, 60, 0.9);}

#main-menu li a {
  color: #777;
  display: block;
  padding: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 12px;}

/*----------------------MENU SPECIFIC COLORS--------------*/
#main-menu li#dhtml_menu-305{
 border-radius:  15px 15px 0px 0px;
 border-right: 2px solid #e6e7de;
 background: #D1B37F;
}
#main-menu li#dhtml_menu-50692{
 border-radius:  15px 15px 0px 0px;
 border-right: 2px solid #e6e7de;
 background: #ffff90;
}
#main-menu li#dhtml_menu-50690{
 border-radius:  15px 15px 0px 0px;
 border-right: 2px solid #e6e7de;
 background: lightblue;
}

#main-menu li#dhtml_menu-50207{
 border-radius:  15px 15px 0px 0px;
 border-right: 2px solid #e6e7de;
 background: #CAC37F;
 }

#main-menu li#dhtml_menu-50207 li{
 background: #CAC37F;
 }

#main-menu li#dhtml_menu-50691{
  border-radius:  15px 15px 0px 0px;
  background: #E4B04A;
}

#main-menu li a:hover {
  border-radius:  15px 15px 0px 0px;
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.7);
  height: 35px;}

#main-menu li a .sf-sub-indicator {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 15;
  text-indent: -9999px;}

#main-menu li ul li a,
#main-menu li ul li a:link,
#main-menu li ul li a:visited {
  border-top-width: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 13px;
  width: 105px;}

#main-menu li ul {
  height: auto;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  left: -9999px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -2px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 15;
  width: 0px;}

#main-menu li ul a {width: 110px;}
#main-menu li ul ul {margin: -33px 0 0 124px;}
#main-menu li:hover>ul,
#main-menu li.sfHover ul {left: auto;}
#main-menu ul li.leaf, #main-menu ul li.expanded, #main-menu ul li.collapsed {list-style:none;}
#main-menu ul.menu li {margin: 0;}
#main-menu li.expanded, #main-menu li.collapsed, #main-menu li.leaf {margin: 0;padding: 0;}
```

**HTML/PHP**

```
  <nav id="navigation" role="navigation">
      <div id="main-menu">
        <?php 
        $main_menu_tree = menu_tree(variable_get('menu_main_links_source', 'main-menu')); 
        print drupal_render($main_menu_tree);
        ?>
      </div>
  </nav><!-- end main-menu -->

  <?php if ($page['header']): ?>
   <div id="header" class="sixteen columns" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;>
    <?php print render($page['header']); ?>
   </div>
   <?php endif; ?>
</div>
     </div>
  </header>
```

**Here is a screenshot**
[image: Click Here]

**Things I've Tried**

I have already tried using :active and :current. For some reason only the first button on my menu has an active class given to it. Cheers!

Comment: we need to see your markup also. CSS is no good unless we know what it is styling.

Comment: Is a particular class applied to the tab when the submenu is activated? It's hard to determine without the HTML. Can you mock up a JSFiddle?

Comment: The problem is that I'm using a drupal menu so the html is done within the program. I will post the php for it though, as well as look into a jsfiddle

Comment: If this is in fact a CSS issue, it might help if you post the rendered HTML instead of the PHP... though your question is unclear to me.  The screenshot is what it looks like now or is it supposed to illustrate the problem?

Comment: It's not a css issue.. I thought the original solution would be to use css, but now I'm thinking I need to give the menu buttons an active or current class using php. As of now (and I put it in the edits) Drupal is only giving one of the buttons an active class. For some reason, when the others are clicked they are not "active." I'll add the rendered html to the end of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is better than a live example:

http://jsfiddle.net/g105b/76JDZ/

[image]

The example uses JavaScript to add the `active` class to the currently selected `li` element, but the effect you are looking for is purely CSS.

A feature of Drupal is to automatically add the class name `active` to the currently selected `li`, so you can completely ignore the JavaScript in the linked example, and simply take the concept shown in CSS.

Comment: Great thank you. What I ended up doing was making a new menu as a block for each of my four menus (setting active on whichever was active). For some reason drupal did not like my original menu. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use `.active` class name. All active menu links in Drupal has a class name `active`.

```
#main-menu li.active
```

If you are willing to select only the menu links that have children, use `.expanded` class name.

```
#main-menu li.expanded
```

Hope this works... Muhammad.

Comment: when I do something like #main-menu li.active {height: 45px;}, is that right? Also (and perhaps more importantly), what defines which object is currently "active"

Comment: Additionally, if I make #main-menu li a.active {height: 45px;} Only the buttons linked to front show as active when on the front page.

Comment: The link takes `.active` class name, when you're viewing the page that this link links to. E.g. (when visiting homepage, any menu link links to the homepage takes the class `.active`. AND when visiting `node/1` page, any menu link links to `node/1` takes the class `.active`)

Comment: For some reason .active isn't working. When I do #main-menu li{height:35px} it works, but as soon as I put li.active it doesn't. With firebug it even states that the button is currently in the active state

Comment: Nevermind, only the home button has  'a' with 'class 'active''